git --work-tree flag is accepted, but git worktree add fails
Am implementing a git-based dotfile version control system.
An alias setting --work-tree=$HOME does not encounter any problems.
alias dotfiles='/usr/bin/git --git-dir="$HOME/.dotfiles/" --work-tree="$HOME"'
But if I attempt to set worktree to $HOME in the repo, it fails, complaining that /home/user already exists.
[~/.dotfiles]$ git worktree add $HOME
#> Preparing worktree (checking out 'user')
#> fatal: '/home/user' already exists

Trying to understand the (apparent) contradiction.
(The real goal is to next bring files within root (/) under version control as well. Would like to understand these git worktree settings better before doing anything that could affect system files outside of $HOME).
Expectation:
if --work-tree flag succeeds. git worktree add would also succeed.

git --work-tree requires an existing path. git worktree add is used to create a new worktree, it refuses to work with existing path. Two completely different things. Try git worktree add --force; see the docs.

Thanks. That makes sense. Offhand, do you happen to know: the docs for git --work-tree reference that: "This can also be controlled by" environement variable or core.worktree configuration. Is that also talking about pointing to the worktree vs setting the worktree?

This is git --work-tree, not git worktree so setting GIT_WORK_TREE environment variable means pointing to the existing worktree.
